# How do I run the code in the Airbnb javascript style guide?

Tags: javascript

I paste the following code

```
var foo = 1,
    bar = foo;

bar = 9;

console.log(foo, bar); // => 1, 9
```

onto [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and [online JavaScript Interpreter](http://math.chapman.edu/~jipsen/js/) but both are not showing anything after clicking run, how do I make it so they work?

Comment: Your JavaScript code works fine...

Comment: Have you opened up your browser's console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log` writes to the browser console. That is why in both the tool and jsfiddle you mentioned you see no output unless you open the browser console (try google for that: "open javascript console {your browser}")

[In the online tool you listed](http://math.chapman.edu/~jipsen/js/) there is a defined function `writeln` which writes to the textarea on the right side. You can therefore try this if you want to see output on the right side:

```
var foo = 1,
    bar = foo;

bar = 9;

writeln(foo); // => 1
writeln(bar); // => 9
```

On jsfiddle, there is no such function.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Google Chrome, try the developer console. It's located in `View > Developer > Javascript console`. You can also try the web developer console on Firefox or the Firebug Console (if you have the firebug add-on in your Firefox installation, obviously).